# DocuSign OrgAdmin API > Activate Membership > Where to get MembershipId?

Tags: docusignapi

In Activate Membership API  (https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/reference/Users/Users/activateMembership) one of path parameter is `MembershipId`.

However I have not found any endpoints that returns responses with `MembershipId`.

The closest guess could be calling `GetUserProfile` that has `Memberships` as parameter, but response does not contain Membership ID:

```
"memberships": [
    {
        "email": "xxxxxx@example.com",
        "account_id": "xxxxxxx-....",
        "external_account_id": "1234546",
        "account_name": "1234546",
        "is_external_account": false,
        "status": "activationSent",
        "permission_profile": {
            "id": 11111111,
            "name": "DocuSign Viewer"
        },
        "created_on": "2020-02-20T12:37:02.757",
        "groups": [...],
        "is_admin": false
    }
]
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your use case? Do you have organizations enabled for your sandbox/demo account? Did you create an org with the Admin tool?

Comment: Yeah, I created organization with the Admin tool and was able to query it with the GET API.

Comment: I am interested in centralized user management using multiple providers and DocuSin Org API in particular.
My guess was that ActivateMembership endpoint was crucial to complete the new user registration flow. 
That is why I am wandering where I could get MembershipId parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}
```

The UserInfo section of the response should include the membershipId